# How do I link the Rest response to the IPN response

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am moving to paypalrest, but have a few questions.
there does not seem to be anything that I can link from my paypal response to the IPN response. 
It would seem that I can get by without IPN except for eCheck payments that are pending, I would need to IPN trigger to let me know when they are completed.

How do I link the Rest response to the IPN response, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup IPN in your PayPal and it will be triggered when new transactions occur.  There really isn't any "linking" to the response necessary.

Comment: when I say link, I want to know what payment it belongs to.
I have it IPN working, but how do I identify what ipn response belongs to what payment?

Comment: The IPN would come with a transaction ID that is unique to any given transaction.  You could also pass your own Invoice ID into the invoice parameter of payment requests and that same value will come back within the IPN so you can log it with the relationship to your original invoice in place.

Comment: I don't see any place to set an invoice number
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Comment: Ah, I guess the REST API doesn't have the invoice parameter.  Yet another reason I've chosen to stick with the Classic API for now.

Comment: I should have also, rest is so much nicer in many ways, but why would they make such a error to leave out invoice number?

Comment: It's just not nearly as a mature as the classic API's.  Not necessarily an error...just a matter of the fact that if they didn't release it until it EVERY single thing the classic API's have...it would never get released.

Comment: Are you working with PHP?  If so, check out my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It'll make all of the classic calls very simple for you.

Comment: I am working with .net and am making my own .net class libs, packaged in a nugget package.

Comment: I have worked out that the saleid is the transaction id in ipn.

Answer (score 0):

When you get payment details from Rest API, then you can find related transacion ID:

```
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
echo $payment->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
```